# append coordinates in an array

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to save all the coordinates of the polyline  whenever user clicks on the map, in an array. However, I have limited the number of clicks to only 2 so that the user will draw only straight lines having lat and long of starting and ending points.
This is my code-

```
var polyOptions = {
    geodesic: true,
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
}
var poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
poly.setMap(map);
var evtListnr = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    var path = poly.getPath();
    if (poly.getPath().getLength() == 1) {
        google.maps.event.removeListener(evtListnr);
    }
    path.push(event.latLng);
    var coordinates_poly = poly.getPath().getArray();
    for (var i = 0; i < coordinates_poly.length; i++) {
        lat_poly = coordinates_poly[i].lat();
        lng_poly = coordinates_poly[i].lng();
    }
    var str_lat_poly = JSON.stringify(lat_poly);
    var str_lng_poly = JSON.stringify(lng_poly);
    document.getElementById("data1").value = 'latitude:"' + str_lat_poly + '"';
    document.getElementById("data2").value = 'longitude:"' + str_lng_poly + '"';
});
}
```

data1 and data2 are two IDs in the form where the coordinates will be saved.

on clicking second time, the lat and long replaces first click's lat and long and only one lat and one long of second click's is there in data1 and data2. I want that the coordinates should append on the first value, Second value should not replace the first one.
Output should be-

Latitude: lat of first click,lat of second click

Longitude:lng of first click, lng of second click

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to make `lat_poly` & `lng_poly` into an array to store all the values. Right now you are just capturing the last value since you use assignment.

```
var lat_poly = [];
var lng_poly = [];
for (var i = 0; i < coordinates_poly.length; i++) {
    lat_poly.push(coordinates_poly[i].lat());
    lng_poly.push(coordinates_poly[i].lng());
}
```